# OOP design: cache data

Tags: c#, performance, oop, caching

I want to design a program so that I can efficiently fetch and display data for users.

The steps are:

1. users specify some settings (SettingOne, SettingTwo, SettingThree...);
2. load different data from database according to different settings;
3. display data;

My problem is that getting data from database is expensive, I can improve the performance by caching data. For example, if both userA and userB ask for `SettingOne` data, I can load data for userA, and cache the result, and give userB the cached result.

Settings are:

```
class Setting {Operation Op, int A, double B, int C, string D}
enum Operation {Op1, Op2, Op3}
// there will be more settings and operations in the future
```

The returned data from database are:

```
// I have no control over this part
Op1: find data based on A and B, return an int
Op2: find data based on C and D, return a string
Op3: find data based on A and D, return an array
```

How can I design a cache class (follow OOP) to efficiently store the data? It means that the code is well-designed so that I can easily add more operations or settings.

---

My C# solution is to use a `Dictionary<Setting, object>` to store data and override `Setting.GetHashCode()`. `object` is not perfect because I need to display data in different forms according to their type (`int`, `string` or `double[]`)

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    switch(Op)
    {
        case Op1: return GetHashCode(A, B);
        case Op2: return GetHashCode(C, D);
        case Op3: return GetHashCode(A, D);
        default: return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: "There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things." -- Phil Karlton